# Microsoft Word: Some Unicode Characters Will not Display in Any Font

Tags: microsoft-word, unicode

When I am using Microsoft Word 2013 on Windows 8, some unicode characters do not display correctly, even when the font is changed to Arial Unicode MS. This affects what to me seems a very bizarre set of characters: o, j and k with a combining macron over the top (0304) all display correctly, but a and e do not (they show the little blank box instead).

Comment: What you are missing is language packs. Sadly it depends on windows version whether you can d/l and install at no cost.  Google "language packs" followed by win version... i.e. "language packs windows 8"

Comment: FWIW I tried ojkae , each followed by 0304, and they all ended up with a combining macron with the MS Arial Unicode font. This is Word 2013 + Win 8.1. The macron was rather to the left over the "j", and in fact the formatting seemed better with other fonts such as Arial. Choosing older per-document compatibility features (you can do this in documents that were created in previous versions of Word) doesn't seem to make much difference. Can you post your document somewhere accessible?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3emk6eu2cu78cbe/Basic%20Sound%20Changes%20in%20Germanic.docx?dl=0 - I think it's a problem with actually inputing the characters, they don't show up on my Mac which is definitely capable of displaying the characters. In addition, I can type ä using the unicode for the whole character, but not when its a followed by ¨.